# How to write this regex without catastrophic backtracking

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

I am trying to write a regex that will get me the contents of the 21st field in this list for the lines that starts with an I, provided that the field contains a number in this format nnn-nnnnnn (like 001-123456):

```
T|112||     |               | |AZ        |D         |1   |       1|
I|   10|ACAA          |BY CORD EACH             |      10.00-|       .99 |     |      .36 |1   |       1|D         |I|CO |BTE  |N| |       .00 |      .00 |15 |1    |001-123456     |ACAA 
I|   20|LEES03        |TINTED OZ                |       2.00-|      6.50 |     |     4.48 |1   |       1|D         |I|FL |LTGE |N| |       .00 |      .00 |45 |1    |001-234555     |JEE  
I|   20|LEES03        |TINTED OZ                |       2.00-|      6.50 |     |     4.48 |1   |       1|D         |I|FL |LTGE |N| |       .00 |      .00 |45 |1    |               |JEE  
I|   20|LEES03        |TINTED OZ                |       2.00-|      6.50 |     |     4.48 |1   |       1|D         |I|FL |LTGE |N| |       .00 |      .00 |45 |1    |001-234552     |JEE
```

Here is the simple regex that I am using, there I am capturing the field content in the 2nd capture group:

```
^I(\|.*?){20}(\d{3}-\d{6})
```

I have read about catastrophic backtracking, but my regex skills are limited and I do not understand how to write this regex so that I do not get the catastrophic backtracking.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you know it has format `nnn-nnnnnn` why not simply use `\d{3}-\d{6}` ?

Comment: @noob I _am_ using that, but I am only interested in the 21st field - I do not want to match this string in any other field.

Comment: Since you other fields don't have number of that pattern merely using that will match 21st field.

Comment: @noob The data in the post is only a _sample_.

Comment: You use a wrong approach. You need to split your string on pipes and then to check if the first field is an `I` and if the 21th field is not empty (or has the format you want).

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte Yes, that is another way to do it, but for my purposes, a regex is my preferred way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can avoid *catastrophic backtracking* by using negation pattern:

```
^I(?:\|[^|]*){20}(\d{3}-\d{6})
```

`[^|]*` matches 0 or more character that are not `|`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pS7vH0/1)

Answer (score 5):

IMO, a better way consists to split the string on pipes and then to check the first and the 21th fields. An example in command line with the autosplit parameter `-a`:

```
perl -F'\|' -anE'say $& if $F[0] eq "I" && $F[20]=~/\S+/' file
```

Example in a script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my @F;
while(<DATA>) {
    @F = split /\|/;
    say $1 if $F[0] eq 'I' && $F[20] =~ /(\d+-\d+)/
}

__DATA__
T|112||     |               | |AZ        |D         |1   |       1|
I|   10|ACAA          |BY CORD EACH             |      10.00-|       .99 |     |      .36 |1   |       1|D         |I|CO |BTE  |N| |       .00 |      .00 |15 |1    |001-123456     |ACAA 
I|   20|LEES03        |TINTED OZ                |       2.00-|      6.50 |     |     4.48 |1   |       1|D         |I|FL |LTGE |N| |       .00 |      .00 |45 |1    |001-234555     |JEE  
I|   20|LEES03        |TINTED OZ                |       2.00-|      6.50 |     |     4.48 |1   |       1|D         |I|FL |LTGE |N| |       .00 |      .00 |45 |1    |               |JEE  
I|   20|LEES03        |TINTED OZ                |       2.00-|      6.50 |     |     4.48 |1   |       1|D         |I|FL |LTGE |N| |       .00 |      .00 |45 |1    |001-234552     |JEE
```

Comment: This is the right way to tackle the problem. Regex to parse a delimited file is just painful.